# Facebook PHP 4.x return array parse

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hey all I am just now getting around to the newest version of the PHP sdk for Facebook. It seems to use a new array of returned data that I can not seem to be able to parse out what I need and not all other gibberish it has contained inside the array.

The array returned looks like this:

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 439676913452345546787863523525
            [name] => John Doe
            [picture] => stdClass Object (
                [data] => stdClass Object (
                    [is_e] =>
                    [url] => https://blah.com....
                )
            )
        )
        [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 56594790468026754634524674
            [name] => Bob Barker
            [picture] => stdClass Object (
                [data] => stdClass Object (
                    [is_e] =>
                    [url] => https://blah.com....
                )
            )
        )
        [2]...etc etc...
        [paging] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cursors] => stdClass Object ( 
                [before] => QWFMmhllXN5JH....Rk52QWc= 
                [after] => WGHtdnNIwaDlRz....05RNB0E= 
            ) 
        )
    )
)
```

In the older version of the Facebook SDK I just needed to do something along these lines (below code example is getting the **id** within the returned array and checking also to make sure it has a value or not):

```
foreach($theReturnedArray['data'] as $rData) {
  $id = (isset($rData['id']) ? $rData['id'] : null);
  $name = (isset($rData['name']) ? $rData['name'] : null);

  echo $name . ' ' . $id . '<br />';
}
```

in order to get the value that I needed. Now the return has an added **stdClass object** within the array itself and I am unsure on how to go about getting *id, name & picture url* from it.

Any help would be awesome!

**ANSWER**

It was caused of an error in my code that I was getting 0's back (the +):

```
 echo $name . ' ' . $id + '<br />';
```

And I needed to change it to:

```
 echo $name . ' ' . $id . '<br />';
```

and the full code together:

```
 foreach($graphObject['data'] as $rData) {
    $id = (isset($rData->id) ? $rData->id : null);
    $name = (isset($rData->name) ? $rData->name : null);
    $picUrl = (isset($rData->picture->data->url) ? $rData->picture->data->url : null);

    echo $id . '<br/>';
    echo $name . '<br/>';
    echo $picUrl . '<br/>';
    echo '======================================<br/>';
 }
```

Comment: FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0#asarray

Comment: Thanks for the link, @CBroe but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get values from objects with `->`

```
echo $rData->id;     // This format is for objects
```

And not

```
echo $rData['id'];   // This format is for arrays
```

So your code would now look like

```
$id = isset($rData->id) ? $rData->id : NULL;
$name = isset($rData->name) ? $rData->name : NULL;
```

Comment: So how about the other
**[picture] => stdClass Object ( [data] => stdClass Object (  [is_e] => [url] => https://blah.com....** array in order to get the picture url?

Comment: Same format. `$rData->picture->url` and `$rData->picture->data` etc

Comment: So should **$theReturnedArray['data']** be **$theReturnedArray->data** as well because im not getting anything other than 0's back.

Comment: Nope that's not needed if that's the actual array that you have posted

Comment: Yes it is but i'm still getting 0's back?

Comment: Can you generate a fiddle with your array and code?

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted